# PHP - CURL works intermittently with strange results

Tags: php, curl, google-drive-api

Please can somebody help with the following.

The code I am using is below to fetch an image from google drive and save it onto my server...

```
function save_image($url_image, $title){

global $document_root;
global $token;

$fullpath = ''.$document_root.'images/temp/'.$token.'/'.$title;

$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init ($url_image);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url_image);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
$rawdata = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if (file_exists($fullpath)){

    unlink($fullpath);

}

$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
$r = fwrite($fp, $rawdata);

fclose($fp);

return $r;

}
```

Sometimes/the majority of the time it works fine however with quite a few images it doesn't work properly.

What happens is (and I can see this when testing) the file is copied into the directory and all looks fine but then after 3 to 4 seconds the file changes into a "corrupted image" according to windows photo viewer.

When it first uploads and I quickly right click on it and edit in code editor before the 3 to 4 seconds it shows an image as you would expect with this type of thing...

ÿØÿà NUL DEL JFIF etc. (I wont post all of it).

But after the 3 to 4 seconds it changes the filesize for one and when I right click and edit it in code editor it comes up with html code and it is the html code of the main page in google drive.

Can anyone begin to think why this might be?

I have googled and googled and haven't come up with an answer.

Thank you
Dan

Comment: You should avoid `global` variable. You are on windows and you use `/` for a path, use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead. You need to check `fopen`, ... returns, and curl error `curl_errno`, `curl_error`. Maybe your issue don't come from this function, because it seems correct.

Comment: I suggest that you use Google Drive API instead